# Create An xml layout to Bitmap Image Android

Tags: android, android-bitmap, bitmapimage

Example of Sharechat app, How to achive it [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUcev.jpg
by using this i can only get the image element and converted as an image but not able to get the framelayout, this has to be done in background without inflating  to main view.

```
 public static Bitmap createBitmapSafely(int width, int height, Bitmap.Config config, int retryCount) {
        //width and height must be > 0
        if (width <= 0 || height <= 0) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, config);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (retryCount > 0) {
                System.gc();
                return createBitmapSafely(width, height, config, retryCount - 1);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

```
 public static Bitmap createBitmapFromView(View view, float scale) {
        if (view instanceof ImageView) {
            Drawable drawable = ((ImageView) view).getDrawable();
            if (drawable != null && drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
                return ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
            }
        }
        view.clearFocus();
        int viewHeight = 0;
        if (view instanceof ScrollView) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((ScrollView) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                viewHeight += ((ScrollView) view).getChildAt(i).getHeight();
            }
        } else if (view instanceof NestedScrollView) {
            for (int i = 0; i < ((NestedScrollView) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
                viewHeight += ((NestedScrollView) view).getChildAt(i).getHeight();
            }
        } else {
            viewHeight = view.getHeight();
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = createBitmapSafely((int) (view.getWidth() * scale),
                (int) (viewHeight * scale), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, 1);
        if (bitmap != null) {
            synchronized (CANVAS) {
                Canvas canvas = CANVAS;
                canvas.setBitmap(bitmap);
                canvas.save();
                // 防止 View 上面有些区域空白导致最终 Bitmap 上有些区域变黑
                canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
                canvas.scale(scale, scale);
                view.draw(canvas);
                canvas.restore();
                canvas.setBitmap(null);
            }
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do. Try explaining exactly what it is you are trying to accomplish (not just a sample image from another app.)

Comment: Need to create a bitmap image like that from XML which is populating in a recycle view.when taping on onitem click.

Comment: It's still not clear what you're trying to accomplish. If you have the `RecyclerView` and the `RecyclerView.ViewHolder` implementation when an item it tapped, what is being captured to a `Bitmap`? Is it just the item which was tapped, or are you trying to capture the entire screen or the entire content the app has drawn on screen?

Comment: @LarrySchiefer its the item need to capture. not the entire screen .

Comment: You should be able to have the `View` draw into the `Canvas` without knowing anything but the width/height of the view. There should be no need to use reflection to determine the view type. But, that means you have to make sure you have the base view of whatever item you wish to "capture". In other words: whatever your on click listener is bound with needs to be able to get the base container view for the `ViewHolder` of that item. Then capture that view (and all its children) by having it draw to the custom `Canvas`.